# How much is too much asp.net session size?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an application on the corporate intranet that makes use of session state to store values between a wizard (string of pages/ user controls).  I'm measuring the size of the session and navigating around to make sure things dotn get out of hand.

At worst, I can get the size up to 900 Bytes.

Is this too much?

I know it all depends on other factors such as the number of users and the amount of memory in the server.  So lets set some parameters around these... The server is allocated 1 Gig of RAM for ASP.net (the rest is allocated to the OS and other items).  I have at most 10 users on the system concurrently.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd say 900 bytes is nothing. Lets say it's 1kB -> which means with 1Gig of RAM you should be able to store roughly 1000k of those sessions (not including anything else).

Personally I think you shouldn't look at the raw numbers. What's important is: is the stuff in the session really meant to be in the session. You should put information in the session that's useful when the user is browsing your website and what can be discarded if the user leaves your website.

As long as you don't store big data objects in your session, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Too much is when you run out of memory attempting to serve whatever user load you want to be able to serve on each machine. We can't tell you how much is too much, but we can tell you that 900 bytes isn't very much at all.

Answer (score 0):

Given your user load, I think you should be alright...

Don't forget to handle the situation where your session drops out halfway through for some reaason.

Answer (score 0):

900 Bytes per session, total? No thats hardly a problem with only 10 users. Even 900K per user wouldnt be much of an issue, as you would only be talking about ~10MB of session state.

900K per page per user would be something you need to worry about.